# Auto-increment ID in create method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, auto-increment

I create a controller for `Category` table and have generated CRUD metods.

[image]

In the `CREATE` action method, how can I make the `CategoryID` input disappear, and after entering `CategoryName`, the `CategoryID` column will automatically increment when adding a new entry to the table.

Comment: Don't do this in the frontend - let the backend database handle this, it's better at stuff like that! If you're using SQL Server - use an `INT IDENTITY` column for your `ID` where SQL Server handles dishing out the unique values

Comment: Where used INT IDENTITY in Visual or SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO?

Comment: You can use both tools - but the `INT IDENTITY` is a **database definition / constraint** - so you need to do this in the database table - not your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the controls (textbox and label) from your create view.

Additionally, you can remove it from the list of parameters the POST method is expecting example

Change this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CategoryID,CategoryName")] Category category)
```

to:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CategoryName")] Category category)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it after work and I'll let you know if it worked